# Redirecting stdout to a file you don't have write permission on

Tags: shell, permissions, io-redirection, sudo, io

When you attempt to modify a file without having write permissions on it, you get an error:

```
> touch /tmp/foo && sudo chown root /tmp/foo
> echo test > /tmp/foo
zsh: permission denied: /tmp/foo
```

Sudoing doesn't help, because it runs the command as root, but the shell handles redirecting stdout and opens the file as you anyway:

```
> sudo echo test > /tmp/foo
zsh: permission denied: /tmp/foo
```

Is there an easy way to redirect stdout to a file you don't have permission to write to, besides opening a shell as root and manipulating the file that way?

```
> sudo su
# echo test > /tmp/foo
```

Comment: Answer for a similar question from StackOverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/82256/how-do-i-use-sudo-to-redirect-output-to-a-location-i-dont-have-permission-to-wri/82278#82278

Answer (score 150, accepted):

Yes, using `tee`. So `echo test > /tmp/foo` becomes

```
echo test | sudo tee /tmp/foo
```

You can also append (`>>`)

```
echo test | sudo tee -a /tmp/foo
```

Comment: Tee will also output to stdout; sometimes you don't want the contents filling the screen. To fix this, do `echo test | sudo tee /tmp/foo > /dev/null`

Comment: How will you do it with heredoc?

Comment: A related question is https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/712933/does-unix-have-a-command-to-read-from-stdin-and-write-to-a-file-like-tee-withou

Answer (score 31):

To replace the content of the file with the output of `echo` (like the `>` shell redirection operator).

```
echo test | sudo dd of=/tmp/foo
```

To write into the file (at the beginning, though you can use `seek` to output at different offsets) without truncating (like the `1<>` Bourne shell operator):

```
echo test | sudo dd of=/tmp/foo conv=notrunc
```

To append to the file (like `>>`), with GNU `dd`:

```
echo test | sudo dd of=/tmp/foo oflag=append conv=notrunc
```

See also GNU `dd`'s `conv=excl` to avoid clobbering an existing file (like with `set -o noclobber` in POSIX shells) and `conv=nocreat` for the opposite (only update an existing file).

Comment: clever!  this alleviates the need to do `echo test | sudo tee /tmp/foo >/dev/null` to discard the output.

Comment: I may have to take that back; [`dd` is unreliable for that](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17295/when-is-dd-suitable-for-copying-data-or-when-are-read-and-write-partial) unless you're using obscure GNU-only options `iflag=fullblock oflag=fullblock`, which remove the elegance of this answer.  I'll stick with `tee`.

Comment: dd is reliable with the non-obscure bs=1

Comment: @umeboshi But reliable only if you're experienced enough to know exactly what you're doing.  For`dd` can be fairly dangerous (if not to say: devastating) if only a *slight* mistake was made. So for new users, I'd rather recommend the `tee` method to be on the safe shore.

Comment: @AdamKatz, in the case of `dd of=file` alone (without `count`/`skip`...), it is reliable. `iflag=fullblock` is not needed because here `dd` writes on output what it has read on input. It doesn't matter if it was not full blocks.

Comment: dd also (by default) outputs status information to stderr.  To fix that add `status=none` to the `dd` command or redirect the status output which goes to stderr using `2> /dev/null`.

Answer (score 15):

`tee` is probably the best choice, but depending on your situation something like this may be enough:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo test > /tmp/foo'
```

Answer (score 4):

While I agree, that `| sudo tee` is the canonical way, sometimes **sed** (here assuming GNU `sed`) may work:

```
cat sudotest 
line 1

sudo sed -i '1iitest' sudotest && cat sudotest 
itest
line 1

sudo sed -i '$aatest' sudotest && cat sudotest 
itest
line 1
atest
```

`-i` modifies the file in place. `1i` means *insert* before line 1. `$a` means *append* after last line.

Or copy to xclipboard:

```
somecommand | xclip
sudo gedit sudotest
move cursor to desired place, click middle mouse button to insert, save
```

Comment: Note that [`sed -i` does not actually modify the file in place](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12696224/4756299) - it creates a temporary file and renames it on exiting.  So you won't be able to do something like `tail -f ...` on the original file and see the output using `sed -i ...` while the pipeline is running

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Yes, since the size may be increased or shrinked, and since that's probably the case for most sed invocations, and you can't even - afaik - write to the same location on SSDs it's only a pseudo 'in place' operation. As a non native english speaker, may I ask for a brief expression, which isn't so likely misinterpreted? Just `-i creates a new file of same name` or is there something more compact? I guess I like `in place`, because it explains the `i`. The gnu-sed manpage calls it *in place* too and the long flag is `--in-place`.

Answer (score 4):

Use `sponge` from the moreutils package. It has the advantage that it does not write to stdout.

```
echo test | sudo sponge /tmp/foo
```

Use the `-a` option to append to a file instead of overwriting it.

Comment: I'm not sure what advantage not writing to stdout presents, but you could just redirect the output to `/dev/null` if it were an issue

Comment: Of course I can redirect to /dev/null, but the command is easier to read and type without the redirection. The advantage of not writing to stdout is that my terminal is not filled with rubbish.

Comment: I would not install a package to spare a redirection, but I regularly use sponge, so it is already there.

Comment: Syntax highlighting is already applied due to the tags on the question, the last edit just made things worse by increasing indentation unnecessarily.

Answer (score 2):

I have been kicking around in the back of my mind ideas for a similar problem, and came up with the following solutions:

- `sudo uncat` where `uncat` is a program that reads standard input and writes it to the file named on the command line, but I haven't written `uncat` yet.
- `sudocat` the variant of `sudoedit` that I haven't written yet that does a cleaner `sudo cat` or `sudo uncat`.
- or this little trick of using `sudoedit` with an EDITOR that is a shell script

  ```
  #!/bin/sh
  # uncat
  cat > "$1"
  ```

  which can be invoked as either `|sudo ./uncat file` or `| EDITOR=./uncat sudoedit` but that has interesting side-effects.

Comment: `cat` takes a list of files to con**cat**inate, therefore uncat should take a list of files to **un** con**cat**inate to. It would have to use magic to decide how much to put in each file. Alternative name include `dog`, `to-file`, `redirect`.

Comment: I can't think of any reason why I would want `uncat` when I have `tee`.

Comment: Well, `tee` has the trivial drawback that it writes its stdin to its stdout — which is trivially mitigated by redirecting the stdout to `/dev/null`.  Other alternatives include `dd of=/tmp/foo` (mentioned in another answer), which writes status information to stderr, and `cp /dev/stdin /tmp/foo`.

Answer (score 1):

The error comes from the order in which the shell does things.

The redirection is handled before the shell even executes `sudo`, and is therefore done with the permissions of the user that you are currently working as.  Since you don't have write permissions to create/truncate the target of the redirection, you get a `permission denied` error from the shell.

The solution is to guarantee that the output file is created under the identity given to you by `sudo`, e.g. with `tee`:

```
$ generate_output | sudo tee target_file
```