# How to insert text into a root-owned file using sudo?

Tags: permissions, sudo, io-redirection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Redirecting stdout to a file you don't have write permission on](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1416/redirecting-stdout-to-a-file-you-dont-have-write-permission-on)

Running a command like `sudo echo 'text' >> /file.txt` fails with:

```
bash: /file.txt: Permission denied
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84882/sudo-echo-something-etc-privilegedfile-doesnt-work

Answer (score 161, accepted):

This doesn't work because the redirection is executed by the shell, not by the command it applies to. But your shell is not running as root, only `echo 'text'` is.

A common trick when you need to have root permissions to write to a file, but not to generate the data, is to use `tee`:

```
echo 'text' | sudo tee -a /file.txt
```

`tee` prints the text to stdout, too. In order to mute it so it behaves more similar to shell appending (`>>`), route the stdout to `/dev/null`:

```
echo 'text' | sudo tee -a /file.txt > /dev/null
```

If you do need root permissions to generate the data, you can run two separate `sudo` commands, or run a shell inside `sudo` and do the redirection there (careful with the quoting).

```
sudo echo 'text' | sudo tee -a /file.txt
sudo sh -c 'echo "text" >>/file.txt'
```

When overwriting rather than appending, if you're used to your shell refusing to truncate an existing file with the `>` operator (`set -o noclobber`), remember that this protection will not apply. `sudo sh -c 'echo >/etc/passwd'` and `sudo tee /etc/passwd` will overwrite `/etc/passwd`, you'd need `sudo sh -o noclobber -c 'echo >/etc/passwd'` for that `noclobber` setting to also be applied to the `sh` started by `sudo`.

Comment: This is definitively the better way, as this lets you easily `echo` complicated statements with newlines and so on. For example I didn’t manage to to the following with `sudo -s`, but with `tee` it was very easy: `echo -e '#!/bin/bash\n\nexport PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages\ngtk-redshiftreal $@' | sudo tee gtk-redshift`

Answer (score 10):

You are telling bash to open a file and append the output of the command `sudo echo 'text'` to it, which of course doesn't work since your bash runs as non-root. Interactively, I usually run `sudo -s` to get around this (since then the shell runs as root and can open the file). Alternatively, you can run `sudo sh -c "echo 'text' >> /file.txt"`, which also works, but is a bit of a hassle with all the interpolation/escaping that can interfere if you have complicated expressions.