# sudo permission denied but su grants permission

Tags: permissions, sudo, su

this is the first occurrence where su was required for me.

I read an article about changing the value in /sys/devices/virtual/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness to alter my laptop's screen brightness.

I first noticed that when I would `$ sudo echo 10 > brightness` I would get permission denied.

I switched to root using su and `# echo 10 > brightness` changed my brightness almost instantly.

The last weird thing to me happened when I tried `# echo 20 > brightness` (maxbrightness file holds the value 15) and I got a write error

Could someone explain this difference between sudo and su to me? Understanding the write error would be an added bonus. Any help, pointers, and/or links would be much appreciated.

Comment: Related http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1416/250

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Redirection does not work that way. Appending `>` to a command will run that redirection as the invoking user (you) and not as root. Do it with [`tee`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_%28command%29):

```
echo 20 | sudo tee /sys/devices/virtual/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

or by invoking the command in a separate privileged shell:

```
sudo bash -c "echo 20 > /sys/devices/virtual/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness"
```

Comment: Like the tee tip. It had not occurred to me during my 15 years of unix sysadmining :-) Obvious when seen.

Answer (score 9):

This isn't because of `sudo`, it's because of the way your command is processed; I actually explained it in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1416/redirecting-stdout-to-a-file-you-dont-have-write-permission-on). When you do

```
$ sudo echo 10 > brightness
```

the shell runs the command `sudo echo 10`, which runs `echo 10` as root. The shell then tries to open `brightness` so it can redirect the output from `echo 10` into it, but it can't -- your shell is running with your permissions, not root. There are workarounds posted as answers on the question I linked to; a good one is:

```
$ echo 10 | sudo tee brightness
```

Now `tee` is the one to open `brightness`, and since it's running as root it succeeds

Answer (score 3):

su = **s** witch **u** ser: Use the shell as a different user

sudo = **s** uper **u** ser **do**: execute following command as the root user.

In your case the following command is only `echo 20`, hence only echo 20 gets executed as root (as said before). 
The redirect is executed as you again.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at `/etc/sudoers` file. If your a/c is not listed there then you will not be able to [`sudo`](http://www.sudo.ws/sudo/sudo.html).

Comment: True, but you'd get a specific error message in that case ("username is not in the sudoers file")