# sudo nt passing after redirection operator

Tags: shell, scripting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [sudo permission denied but su grants permission](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6713/sudo-permission-denied-but-su-grants-permission)

I am trying to echo a new value into a file using following command

```
  sudo echo 4096 > /proc/sys/fs/file-max
```

The error coming is permission denied.But when I do the same thing as a root user I am successful.Can I know the reason why it happens or we can say that sudo doesnt pass through the ">" operator

Answer (score 4):

sudo does not pass through the > operator because it never sees it. The shell interprets the > character and sudo only sees echo 4096. This means that the shell as your user id tries to open /proc/sys/fs/file-max and thus fails.

Work arounds:

```
% echo 4096 | sudo dd of=/proc/sys/fs/file-max
% sudoedit /proc/sys/fs/file-max
```

Comment: Mel's right on the thing about sudo not seeing the redirect, but I'd use tee, not dd, since mistakes with dd...well, there's a reason they call it disk destroyer! `echo 4096 | sudo tee /proc/sys/fs/file-max`

Comment: @maco There's absolutely _no_ difference whether you use `dd` or `tee` for this, as long as you don't accidentially mistype "/dev/sda1" instead of "/proc/sys/fs/file-max" :)