# permissions issues writing to /proc

Tags: permissions, proc

New to Linux attempting an exercise to overwrite `/proc/sys/fs/file-max`

`sudo sh -c 300000 > file-max` returns `bash: file-max: Permission denied`. Do I actually have to be root to do this? the user account I'm using has been added to the sudo user group.

I saw variations of this question posted mostly attempting to modify different folders and the above command was the recommendation to alleviate the issue, but is the `/proc` directory different?

Note: using most recent Kali Linux release.

Comment: You should not comment on your own question (except for responses to other comments) but edit it.

Comment: @Tor Where did you see that recommended? That command would try to start a shell to run a command called `300000`, which probably isn't going to be found (even if the redirection succeeds)

Comment: Also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6713/sudo-permission-denied-but-su-grants-permission

Answer (score 3):

Your proposed command is nonsensical.  `sudo sh -c 300000 > file-max` will attempt to have a superuser shell run the command `300000` and redirect the output into a file called `file-max` in the nonsuperuser shell's current working directory.

You are probably instead looking to do something like:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo 300000 > /proc/fs/file-max'
```

That said, writing directly to `/proc` is a somewhat hacky way to alter these properties.  A more "respectable" way to effect this change would be:

```
sudo sysctl -w fs.file-max=300000
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem there is that `/proc/file-max` is being overwritten as your user and not root.

Do:

```
echo 300000 | sudo tee /proc/sys/fs/file-max
```

or:

```
sudo sysctl -w fs.file-max=300000
```

You must restart your network for the change to take effect. The command to manually restart the network is the following:

```
sudo service networking restart
```

You should also add `fs.file-max=300000` to `/etc/sysctl.conf` for the setting to survive a reboot of the server.

```
echo "fs.file-max=300000" | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew that had something to do with it but I wasn't entirely certain what order to use to utilize tee! Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

The redirection is executed before `sudo` thus `sudo` cannot elevate the permissions of the redirection. You need a shell with root permissions to do this:

```
sudo bash -c 'echo 300000 >/proc/sys/fs/file-max'
```