# Why can't sudo redirect stdout to /etc/file, but sudo 'nano' or 'cp' can?

Tags: permissions, sudo, io-redirection

Why does redirection, using `sudo` give me an error for the following commands?

```
$ sudo printf "foo" >/etc/file
bash: /etc/file: Permission denied

$ sudo printf "foo" ~/file; cat ~file >/etc/file 
bash: /etc/file: Permission denied
```

...yet I have no such problem when I use an editor, or `cp`.
I don't think I've ever tried this before, so I don't know if there is something haywire on my system, or if this is normal. It seems a bit restrictive to be normal, but(?) maybe it is intended to be restrictive... 
(using Ubuntu)

Comment: [Redirecting stdout to a file you don't have write permission on](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1416)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It is normal. The file after the `>` is not open by the process running under `sudo`, but by the shell, which isn't. Try this instead:

```
printf "foo" | sudo tee /etc/file
```

Comment: Got it, thanks.. so this works too, `sudo sh -c 'printf "foo" >/etc/file'`

Comment: Also, as mentioned in the Q/A linked to by Gilles comment, `tee -a ` caters for appending to a file...