# where should I put the sudo in this command?

Tags: debian

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Redirecting stdout to a file you don't have write permission on](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1416/redirecting-stdout-to-a-file-you-dont-have-write-permission-on)

`echo "some words" >> /etc/apt/source.list`

`permission denied`

`sudo echo "some words" >> /etc/apt/source.list`

also return permission denied

Then I think maybe the append operator is another command, I should put the sudo before it, so  I try

`echo "some words" >> sudo /etc/apt/source.list`

also return permission denied

how should I do this task?

Comment: Related SO question: [How do I use sudo to redirect output to a location I don't have permission to write to?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/82256)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`sudo sh -c 'echo "some words" >> /etc/apt/source.list'`

The reason sudo echo "some words" >> /etc/apt/source.list doesn't work is because sudo is raising the privileges of the 'echo' command, and not the redirection.

The >> redirection causes the current shell to create/append to the file. It fails because your shell doesn't have permissions to do so.

The reason my answer works is that you are running the whole thing (echo and the redirection) in a new shell that has been sudo'd. `sh -c ...` invokes a new shell and runs the command given in that subshell. The sudo before it makes that subshell run withe escalated privileges.

The second sudo example doesn't make sense, because sudo takes a command to run, and that's not what you are passing. I bet you do have a file in the local directory called sudo now with contents "some words". Feel free to delete that :-)

Answer (score 10):

```
echo "some words" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/source.list > /dev/null
```

`-a` is for "append to file"; tee usually overwrites the target file. See `man tee`.

Answer (score -3):

whats wrong in using cat?

```
sudo cat >> /etc/apt/source.list
some words
^D
```

but I like using tee as Daniel said :-)

Comment: Probably the same as with `echo` - obviously, the `>>` fails because it is not included in the `sudo`ification.

Answer (score -3):

```
echo "some words" | sudo cat >> /etc/apt/source.list
```

Comment: Does not work, for the same reason as Nikhil's answer.