# i3wm amixer controls from i3status

Tags: audio, i3, volume

I can run `bindsym button4 exec amixer -D pulse sset Master 5%+` and `bindsym button5 exec amixer -D pulse sset Master 5%-` to adjust the volume from a terminal session. However when I add the commands to my config for i3 like so:

```
 bar {
         #status_command i3status
         #status_command i3blocks -c ~/.i3/i3blocks.conf
         #status_command ~/.i3/Bar.sh
         status_command conky -c /etc/config/conky/conky.conf

         font pango:Monospace
         colors {
                 background $bg-color
                 separator #757575
                 #                  border             background         text
                 focused_workspace  $bg-color          #000000          $text-color
                 inactive_workspace $inactive-bg-color $inactive-bg-color $inactive-text-color
                 urgent_workspace   $urgent-bg-color   $urgent-bg-color   $text-color
         }

         bindsym button4 exec amixer -D pulse sset Master 5%+
         bindsym button5 exec amixer -D pulse sset Master 5%-
 }
```

I have an error in my config:

```
ERROR: CONFIG: Expected one of these tokens: <end>, '#', 'set', 'i3bar_command', 'status_command', 'socket_path', 'mode', 'hidden_state', 'id', 'modifier', 'position', 'output', 'tray_output', 'font', 'binding_mode_indicator', 'workspace_buttons', 'verbose', 'colors', '}'
ERROR: CONFIG: (in file /home/kalenpw/.i3/config)
ERROR: CONFIG: Line 206:        }
ERROR: CONFIG: Line 207:        
ERROR: CONFIG: Line 208:        bindsym button4 exec amixer -D pulse sset Master 5%+
ERROR: CONFIG:                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ERROR: CONFIG: Line 209:        bindsym button5 exec amixer -D pulse sset Master 5%-
ERROR: CONFIG: Line 210: }
ERROR: CONFIG: Expected one of these tokens: <end>, '#', 'set', 'i3bar_command', 'status_command', 'socket_path', 'mode', 'hidden_state', 'id', 'modifier', 'position', 'output', 'tray_output', 'font', 'binding_mode_indicator', 'workspace_buttons', 'verbose', 'colors', '}'
ERROR: CONFIG: (in file /home/kalenpw/.i3/config)
ERROR: CONFIG: Line 207:        
ERROR: CONFIG: Line 208:        bindsym button4 exec amixer -D pulse sset Master 5%+
ERROR: CONFIG: Line 209:        bindsym button5 exec amixer -D pulse sset Master 5%-
ERROR: CONFIG:                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ERROR: CONFIG: Line 210: }
ERROR: CONFIG: Line 211: 
ERROR: FYI: You are using i3 version 4.7.2 (2014-01-23, branch "tags/4.7.2")
```

I'm mirroring the syntax found on the i3wm user guide:

```
bar {
    # disable clicking on workspace buttons
    bindsym button1 nop
    # execute custom script when scrolling downwards
    bindsym button5 exec ~/.i3/scripts/custom_wheel_down
}
```

It appears to me like the syntax is right and the issue is definitely with those 2 bindsym lines because it is fine without them. How can I fix this so I can control the volume when I scroll on the statusbar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your i3 version is very old, you need to update it to at least 4.11 (bindsym for i3bar is mentioned in its [release notes](https://github.com/i3/i3.github.io/blob/master/downloads/RELEASE-NOTES-4.11.txt)).

You can find the user's guide for your version [here](https://i3wm.org/docs/4.7/userguide.html).

Comment: I'm following the page here: http://i3wm.org/docs/repositories.html and after running the first command(`sudo echo 'deb http://dl.bintray.com/i3/i3-autobuild-ubuntu wily main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/i3-autobuild.list`) I get  bash: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/i3-autobuild.list: Permission denied so I can't update. How can I fix that?

Comment: You can't just stick sudo in front of echo with a redirection (for reasons check [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25747/where-should-i-put-the-sudo-in-this-command/25748#25748) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82256/how-do-i-use-sudo-to-redirect-output-to-a-location-i-dont-have-permission-to-wr) or [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1416/redirecting-stdout-to-a-file-you-dont-have-write-permission-on)). You'll need to open a shell as root or use one of the workarounds in the questions I linked.

Comment: Opened a terminal as root and it works great now. Thanks for the quick answer!