# Why can I copy files to, but not create files in, this directory?

Tags: permissions, directory, sudo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Redirecting stdout to a file you don't have write permission on](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1416/redirecting-stdout-to-a-file-you-dont-have-write-permission-on)

I'm trying to create an `md5sum` for an ISO image created with the Ubuntu Customization Kit tools.  The ISO is created by the tools, which have to be run with `sudo`, in

```
~/tmp/remaster-new-files/
```

which has permissions:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root remaster-new-files
```

So I `cd` to that directory and run

```
sudo md5sum my.iso > my.iso.md5
```

and I get the following error:

```
bash: my.iso.md5: Permission denied
```

I can create the md5 sum somewhere else and use `sudo mv` to move it into place, exactly where it would be if the `sudo md5sum` command succeeded.  Also, if I change user to `root` with `sudo su root`, I can run the `md5sum` command successfully.  Why can't I use `sudo` to create files in this directory, given that I can use `sudo` to move files to it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that the redirection is done from the shell *before* running the command, as the current user, so `sudo` do not come into play.

Use instead

```
md5sum my.iso | sudo tee my.iso.md5
```

Comment: Thanks - that's exactly the nugget of information I was missing!

Comment: That's an interesting way of doing it.  Most of the time suggestions just wrap the command and redirection in a `sudo bash -c ""` command...  +1

Comment: For those who haven't used `tee`, note that this will also print the contents to the console, and so shouldn't be used on binary or untrusted inputs.