# permission denied when redirecting sudo sed output

Tags: permissions, sudo, io-redirection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Redirecting stdout to a file you don't have write permission on](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1416/redirecting-stdout-to-a-file-you-dont-have-write-permission-on)

I'm trying to install drupal according to the instructions given in this tutorial:
http://how-to.linuxcareer.com/how-to-install-drupal-7-on-ubuntu-linux
and am stuck on a step:

```
$ cd /etc/apache2/sites-available
$ sudo sed 's/www/www\/drupal/g' default > drupal
bash: drupal: Permission denied
```

The permissions for `/var/www/drupal` are set to 777.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tutorial does not use `sudo` and requires a root shell. You can get a root shell with `sudo -i`.

In case you prefer `sudo`, the redirection is handled by the shell and not by the `sudo` command. So you can't create a file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` by directing the output as you did. According to the `sudo` manual, you should use a subshell like:

```
$ cd /etc/apache2/sites-available
$ sudo sh -c "sed 's/www/www\/drupal/g' default > drupal"
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you are not at `/var/www/drupal/`. You are trying to create the file `drupal` at `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`. If you want the file to be created at `/var/www/drupal`:

```
sed 's/www/www\/drupal/g' default >/var/www/drupal/drupal
```

Otherwise:

```
sed 's/www/www\/drupal/g' default | sudo tee drupal
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the permissions on `/etc/apache2/sites-available` are not 777, and that's where you're writing your output to. The redirection is processed separately from the `sudo`, and you don't have write permissions there. Now, there's nothing about `/var/www/drupal` there, is that where you're trying to write to? If so you can either use `su -c "sed 's/www/www\/drupal/g' default > /var/www/drupal"` or `sed 's/www/www\/drupal/g' default | sudo tee drupal`.