# /dev/console behavior that makes no sense to me

Tags: x11, sudo, console

[Context: After I read [Linux: Difference between /dev/console , /dev/tty and /dev/tty0](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60641/linux-difference-between-dev-console-dev-tty-and-dev-tty0),  I invented a few tests to check my understanding. As a result, I learned that my understanding  of /dev/console is NON-EXISTANT :). It's possible that some points raised here should also be added as comments to the question above]

I am running arch linux, and there is no "console="  kernel parameter at boot time. The output of dmesg contains the following three lines, written during boot:

```
[    0.183964] printk: console [tty0] enabled
...
[    4.908815] fbcon: Deferring console take-over
...
[    5.217652] fbcon: Taking over console
```

Question 1: The QA I link to above asserts that

> /dev/console is a virtual set of devices which ...  by default points to /dev/tty0.

What is the actual meaning of "points to"? is that the same as "is a link to"? If so, is it a hard link or a soft link?

---

Now I start X on my system. I use openbox, and as is usual these days, the desktop is shown on the FIRST virtual console. (That is, Alt-Ctl-F2 gets me a new login terminal, and Alt-Ctl-F1 gets me back to my gui-desktopi). I get the following by typing into the first xterm that opens on the desktop:

```
crw------- 1 root root 5,  1 Nov 30 01:07 /dev/console
crw-rw-rw- 1 root tty  5,  0 Nov 29 23:23 /dev/tty
crw--w---- 1 root tty  4,  0 Nov 30 01:07 /dev/tty0
crw-rw---- 1 root uucp 4, 64 Nov 29 23:15 /dev/ttyS0
[root@scott-dell7577 ~]# tty
/dev/pts/0
```

So in this case /dev/console seems not to point to anything.

Question 2:  Is it because "fbcon took over the console" that /dev/console no longer points to /dev/tty0?  Does /dev/console point to some other 'underlying' raw device?

---

Now I have a REAL problem: I can't look at the output of /dev/console.  In the old days,  X put its graphical interface on terminal 7, and I could see output to /dev/console by choosing Alt-Ctl-F1. But now, the GUI is itself on Terminal 1, and I can't see how to "peek underneath" the deskop to see the console character table. The only two ways I can think of to view /dev/console are 1. to kill X via Alt-Ctrl-Backspace;  or  2. use netconsole to view the console output on a remote machine.

Question 3:  Am I correct that when i kill X, I will then see all the messages that were written to the console while X was running. Is there some way to view console output by "peeking" at the underlying terminal on which the GUI is being displayed? Or perhaps I can modify the startx script so that the GUI will display  on the second virtual terminal and not the first? 
Is there some reason that this big change -- moving the GUI to the first VT where it now covers the console -- was instituted? It seems to have the considerable disadvantage of making it next to impossible to see the console output, so I'd like to understand what benefit it brings.

---

Now is when things get truly weird for me.  I know that only root can write to /dev/console.  Following on from the QA cited above, I typed the following into a non-root xterm on the dekstop.   Can you explain the response to the last command?

```
[scott@scott-dell7577 ~]$ echo hello >/dev/console
bash: /dev/console: Permission denied
[scott@scott-dell7577 ~]$ su 
Password: 
[root@scott-dell7577 scott]#  echo hello >/dev/console
[root@scott-dell7577 scott]# exit
exit
[scott@scott-dell7577 ~]$ sudo echo hello  > /dev/console
bash: /dev/console: Permission denied
```

As an ordinary user, I get permission denied when trying to write to the console. I su to root, and now I get no error.  (Of course, i also get no echoed output,  I believe that's because as I stated above, the console output is "hidden underneath" the GUI.)
I then exit root, and run the same command via sudo. WTF?

Question 5: What is the difference between running the command as root and then running it via sudo, that one should  be allowed and the other forbidden?

---

As a final exercise, I did set up the netconsole  facility, following the directions [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Netconsole). Everything seemed to connect, all diagnostic/verbose output suggested that the console was in fact being redirected. But when I would enter the command

> ## echo hello > /dev/console
>
> on the local machine, there was no error.  But no "hello" appeared either.  Could it be some sort of simple buffering issue that causes writes to /dev/console not to appear at the remote end of the pipe?

Sorry to drone on, but i found it upsetting to see reality agreeing so poorly with what I expected. The two biggest issues being, of course, 1. that there is a command which the root can perform but returns "Permission denied " when run with sudo; and 2.  that using the new default of   having X display on /dev/ttyS0 seems to make it impossible to see /dev/console output.

Thanks for any  correct answers to these five questions!

Comment: Hint: In the command `sudo echo hello  > /dev/console` which parts are done as the regular user, and which part is done as root? Have you tried `sudo sh -c 'echo hello > /dev/console'`? Second hint: `/dev/console` is not a link of any kind, it is a special file; "points to tty0" simply means that is refers to the same physical device as tty0.

Comment: `sudo echo hello > /dev/console`: this has been already explained to death: it's not `sudo` (or the command run by it) which does the redirection and tries to open `/dev/console`, but the shell it's called from, which does not run as root. The shell will perform the redirections between the fork() and exec().

Comment: Right of course, sorry. But thanks. Should I just edit out the sudo related nonsense and the link question?  That would focus on the real issue of how to view the console output:  1. when i set up netconsole and then enter "echo hello > /dev/console" as root, is it normal that nothing comes out at the remote end ? (perhaps because of the hello is stuck in some buffer? how to minimize  such buffering); and 2. even if i can get the netconsole pipe to display console output on a remote machine, is there a simple way to view console output when the console tty is buried under the X desktop?

Comment: Yes, tidy it up. Also put all the stuff about "netconsole" in a different question, since, according to first paragraph from the very [link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Netconsole) from your Q: Name "netconsole" is a misnomer because it's not really a "console", more like a remote logging service ;-)

Comment: This site works on the one-question-per-question principle.  I already answered question 3 (which is _itself_ multiple questions in one) at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/480705/5132 in 2018.  All of the stuff after question 3 has already been asked over and over here for years, including at https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/31322/5132 for example.

Answer (score 0):

> ~ Where did the `echo hello >/dev/console` go?

That will go either to:

1. `/dev/tty0` (the active virtual terminal: the last of `/dev/tty1`, `/dev/tty2`, etc that was switched to, which may be hidden behind your GUI).
2. a serial or virtual terminal specified by the last `console=ttyXXX` kernel boot command line argument.
3. another tty where `/dev/console` was later redirected with `ioctl(fd, TIOCCONS)`. That redirection will only affect userland output to `/dev/console` (kernel messages will **not** be redirected). Also, to make it more fun, there's absolutely no way to determine where it has been redirected ;-)

In any case, echoing stuff to `/dev/console` does not cause it to become a kernel message and appear in dmesg (and wherever kernel messages are redicted via `netconsole` or other facility).

> > [`/dev/console`] by default points to `/dev/tty0`.
>
> What is the actual meaning of "points to"? is that the same as "is a link to"? If so, is it a hard link or a soft link?

No, `/dev/console` is a separate character device (just like `/dev/tty` => controlling terminal or `/dev/tty0` => active virtual terminal). All the magic happens in the kernel. To get the actual terminal `/dev/console` points to (not the one it was redirected to as per point 3. above), you could use the `TIOCGDEV` ioctl. [Unlike `/dev/tty`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/541531/308316), that could be used reliably with `/dev/console`, since `/dev/console` cannot refer a pseudo-tty.

> Is there some way to view console output by "peeking" at the underlying terminal on which the GUI is being displayed?

There's [`/dev/vcs*`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/vcs.4.html), but vts aren't properly updated while behind a GUI; new data keeps overwriting the last line, instead of causing them to scroll.

```
# perl -0777 -CO -e '
   $c = unpack 'xC', <>; close ARGV;
   $t = join "", map chr $_, unpack "L*", <>;
   s/(.{$c})/$1\n/g, s/ +$//mg, s/\n+$/\n/ for $t;
   print $t
' /dev/vcs{a,u}
...
content of the active vt
...
```