# How do I append text to a write protected file

Tags: files

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Redirecting stdout to a file you don't have write permission on](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1416/redirecting-stdout-to-a-file-you-dont-have-write-permission-on)

I am trying to append a line of text to a write protected file.

I tried to accomplish this with `sudo echo "New line to write" >> file.txt` but I get a permission denied error — presumably because it is trying to sudo the string, not the act of appending it to a file.

If I run `sudo vi file.txt` and authenticate I can happily write away.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you mean `sudo echo  "New line ..` in your post?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use the command below

```
echo "New line to write" | sudo tee -a file.txt
```

Comment: If you're concatenating a lot of data, and/or you're on a particularly slow (or expensive) connection, you should add `>/dev/null` to the `tee` side of the pipe.

Answer (score 4):

I always do such stuff like this: `su -c "echo \"Appended.\" >> test.txt"` (and I'd be happy to learn how (if) it differs from those other solutions).

Comment: How it differs from the other solution is that it doesn't output to stdin. So it would effectively be the same as the very awkwardly written `echo "bla" | sudo tee -a file.txt > /dev/null`.