# modify text file with only one number subject to constraints

Tags: text-processing

I have a text file a.txt whose content is a number between 0 and 100.
I need a single command which modifies a.txt by increasing by 10 the number, but under the constraint that the final result has to be less than 100 (i.e. if the number reaches a value larger than 100 (e.g. 95+10=105), it just stays on 100).

I need also a command to decrease by  at most 10 but in such a way that the final result is greater or equal than 0, it should be analogous.

What I can do, is to modify the file directly with echo, but in this way I can just replace the number with something else (and not adding to the previous number).

Comment: Sounds like home work... What did you do so far? Selected a weapon of choice?

Comment: not homework XD just trying to adjust the backlight with a custom command

Comment: The only solution which makes the fn keys work, conflicts with the shutdown process, so I have to go for a homemade one

Comment: Ha—I read the question and I thought, "Sounds like he's adjusting his screen brightness manually."  Then I came to the comments.  :)  I actually wrote a script for this when I first learned `bash`; it's far from my standards now but it worked well enough.  It's on a computer at home, though, so I'll have to post it later.

Comment: yes, I was about to write it in the post, but then I thought I would have got a lot of people asking to change the grub file instead XD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will add 10:

```
echo "$(awk '{x=$0+10;if(x>100)x=100; print x}' a.txt)" > a.txt
```

This will subtract 10:

```
echo "$(awk '{x=$0-10;if(x<0)x=0; print x}' a.txt)" > a.txt
```

`$0` is the value of the current line being read in the file, so it add/subtract 10 from it, and then check if it is within the constraints.

Thanks to the great comment Wildcard made, you can do this without using a temporary file.

Comment: One note about editing files in place: You can do this without a temp file like so:  `echo "$(awk '{...}' a.txt)" > a.txt`  It's a handy way to use `bash` internals (command substitution) instead of messing with temp file creation.  Credit to http://serverfault.com/a/547331/313521

Comment: Also note that using `tmp` as a tempfile is a nice security hole.  If a symlink called `tmp` is created to point to `/etc/passwd` and you run your script privileged...nasty things happen.  If you do want to use a temp file rather than command substitution as I describe above, use the `mktemp` utility: `tmp="$(mktemp)"; awk '...' a.txt > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" a.txt` though this won't preserve ACLs, extended attributes, hard links, etc. etc. etc.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for this hint! I was very upset for using this temporary file, but I didn't know how to do it without it. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Sure.  :)  Note that I just learned (in the comments on http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/249807/135943) that any trailing newlines will be dropped in command substitution.  In this use case where the file only contains a single line (and it most use cases) it won't matter at all, but it's worth noting.

Comment: An issue: how do I modify a protected text file with that? strangely enough, sudo echo does not work

Comment: Can you still modify it manually like `echo 42 > a.txt`?

Comment: @Reyx_0: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1416/135943

Answer (score 1):

```
read bl <a.txt; echo "$((bl<90?bl+10:100))" >a.txt
```

...should work if there's only a single line in `a.txt` which works out to a number less than or equal to 100. it will also work if `a.txt` is empty in most shells to set it to a value of 10. The reverse logic works:

```
 read bl <a.txt; echo "$((bl<10?0:bl-10))"  >a.txt
```