# Send a message to a "screen" to be received by a device on /dev

Tags: gnu-screen, devices, bluetooth

My question may looks trivial... But it's because despite of my long experience of linux/unix/osx systems, I found myself lacking some basic notions.

I created a little bluetooth/arduino switch to control some appliances at home. It's a simple program like shown here http://www.tinkernut.com/2014/03/arduino-bluetooth-basics/

To enable or disable my switch, I do :

```
screen /dev/tty.HC-06-DevB
```

Then I type 0 or 1 in the console and my switch goes On or Off.

It works. Really, it's nothing difficult... Except that I don't know the principles behind the communication with the ressources located in /dev/ and I don't know how to start learning.

How can I have a simple commande to send 1 or 0 to this particular device? Something like:

```
echo 1 > screen /dev/tty.HC-06-DevB
```

I tried the command below, it doesn't work:

```
echo 1 > /dev/tty.HC-06-DevB
zsh: resource busy: /dev/tty.HC-06-DevB
```

Where to learn what are these "things" in /dev ?

PS : I am using OS X El Capitan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many reading, and thanks to Bibek_G's answer which helped me to find some links on the internets, I finally understood what I need and how to make thing work.
Actually, what I want to do doesn't need screen... The right command was :

```
sudo echo 1 > /dev/cu.HC-06-DevB
```

It didn't work at the beginning because I didn't use `sudo`.

By the way, I also learned how to use `screen`.

Thank you all.

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem was before, but this [doesn't change anything](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1416/redirecting-stdout-to-a-file-you-dont-have-write-permission-on). You ran `echo` as root using `sudo`, but the redirection is handled by your shell and is unaffected

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](http://ss64.com/osx/screen.html) the manual for `screen`. Look for the specific command line options to the `screen` that you're interested in.

For example, `-r` reattaches to a detached screen process.
`-R` reattaches if possible and starts a new session otherwise. I think this is the option you're looking for.

So, I'd do:

```
$ screen -R /dev/tty.HC-06-DevB
```

Also from the manual page:

> -D (-r)       Detach and logout remote (and reattach here).

*Feel free to comment if you think I misunderstood something.*