# Getting "permission denied" when trying to append text onto a file using sudo

Tags: bash, permissions, sudo

I'm using Amazon Linux.  I'm trying to append some text onto a file.  The file is owned by root.  I thought by using "sudo", I could append the needed text, but I'm getting "permission denied", see below

```
[myuser@mymachine ~]$ ls -al /etc/yum.repos.d/google-chrome.repo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 186 Jul 31 15:50 /etc/yum.repos.d/google-chrome.repo
[myuser@mymachine ~]$ sudo echo -e "[google-chrome]\nname=google-chrome\nbaseurl=http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/rpm/stable/\$basearch\nenabled=1\ngpgcheck=1\ngpgkey=https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub" >> /etc/yum.repos.d/google-chrome.repo
-bash: /etc/yum.repos.d/google-chrome.repo: Permission denied
```

How can I adjust my statement so that I can append the necessary text onto the file?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You have to use `tee` utility to redirect or append streams to a file which needs some permissions, like:

```
echo something | sudo tee /etc/file
```

or for append

```
echo something | sudo tee -a /etc/file
```

because by default your shell is running with your own user permissions and the redirection `>` or `>>` will be done with same permissions as your user, you are actually running the `echo` using the `sudo` and redirecting it without `root` permission.

As an alternative you can also get a root shell then try normal redirect:

```
sudo -i
echo something >> /etc/pat/to/file
exit
```

or `sudo -s` for a non-login shell.

you can also run a non interactive shell using root access:

```
sudo bash -c 'echo something >> /etc/somewhere/file'
```

Answer (score 3):

The explanation given in the previous answer is basically correct.
The command before the redirection is run with elevated privileges, but not the redirection itself.

Here is another method which will do what you want.
It has not been mentioned here or in the answers to the [question that this is a duplicate of](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1416/redirecting-stdout-to-a-file-you-dont-have-write-permission-on).
I include it here for completeness.

```
sudo su -c 'echo -e "some\ntext" >> /other/file'
```

Comment: This does not add anything of value that the accepted answer does not already have. Ravexina included a `bash -c` example in their answer (which pretty much does the same thing as `su -c`) so this one is really completely unnecessary.

Comment: It shows another way of completing this task that is not mentioned in any of the other answers. Consider also when bash is not installed, this is more like `sudo $SHELL -c '...'`. Furthermore, the other answer doesn't use `echo`s escape option (not that the OP would miss that). That said, this whole question doesn't add anything. Hence, I flagged it as a duplicate.

Comment: This works for me and the accepted answer does not. 
It keeps telling me "permission denied"