# Insert newline in empty file

Tags: sed, permissions

When creating a new empty file, how do I then add a newline to it?

Running these commands:

```bsh
$ touch test.txt
$ sed -i '$a\' test.txt
$ sed -i '1s/^/\n/' test.txt
$ wc -c test.txt
0 test.txt
```

it is clear `sed` had no effect.

My intention is to write to a new file which at all times has the correct permissions. Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40311745) answer an empty file is created, but I'm having trouble editing the file non-interactively.

Using `echo` is not desirable, because it does not preserve permissions, as seen in this example:

```bsh
$ sudo echo "text" > test.txt
$ stat -c "%U:%G" test.txt
me:mygroup
```

Comment: What permissions do you want the new file to have?  You're trying to use `sudo ... > file`, but [that won't create/write the new file with sudo permissions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1416/redirecting-stdout-to-a-file-you-dont-have-write-permission-on).

Comment: How come `echo > test.txt` does not preserve permissions? `touch test.txt; chmod 200 test.txt; echo >test.txt; ls -l test.txt` => `--w-------`

Comment: "My intention is to write to a new file which at all times has the correct permissions." - Then don't change the permissions.

Comment: Note that the redirection is not done as root in your last example, but by whoever is running the current interactive shell.

Answer (score 0):

These commands worked for me:

```
touch test.txt
stat  test.txt
cat test.txt
echo "" >>test.txt
cat test.txt
stat  test.txt
```

If you do

`echo " " > test.txt`

It will create a new file from scratch, need to use >> to append the CR.

Maybe that was causing your problem.

Comment: Using `>` to an existing file will not recreate the file, i.e. it will not _delete_ the file and create a new file. It will however truncate the contents of the file. Any meta data associated with the file (permission and ownership) will not be altered.