# Copying key to /root/.ssh/authorized_keys

Tags: shell-script, ssh, file-copy, key-authentication, sshpass

I'm trying to copy a file (contains keys) to remote machine using below script.  But the below error

#### /root/.ssh/authorized_keys: Permission denied

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in `cat hosts`

do cat team.keys | sshpass -f pass ssh -t  -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no"  normal_user@ad@${i} "sudo cat >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys";

done
```

--
Please share you suggest to identify solution.

Comment: Related: [Redirecting stdout to a file you don't have write permission on](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1416/redirecting-stdout-to-a-file-you-dont-have-write-permission-on)

Comment: How about /etc/ssh/sshd_config?
Are you allowing PubkeyAuthentication, RSAAuthentication, AuthorizedKeysFile and PermitRootLogin?

Comment: You may want to have a look at `ssh-copy-id` to do things properly. And of course `StrictHostKeyChecking no` is not a good idea. `accept-new` instead of `no` would at least keep some level of protections.

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo cat >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

This command will not do what you think it does.

The shell (running as a regular user) will implement the redirection before it even begins to execute the `sudo cat` command. As a result, the redirection happens as a non-root user, which clearly won't have permission to write into root's `authorized_keys` file.

The standard workaround is to use the `tee` command with sudo instead:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $(cat hosts)

do cat team.keys | sshpass -f pass ssh -t -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" \ 
    normal_user@ad@${i} "sudo tee -a /root/.ssh/authorized_keys >/dev/null"

done
```

In this version, the remote shell running as `normal_user@ad` will execute the command as `sudo <some parameters for sudo> >/dev/null`, and the `sudo` command will gain root access and execute `tee /root/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

The `tee` command will receive the keys piped in from standard input, and will write one copy of its input into the `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` file, which it can do because it's running as root, and pass another copy into standard output. The extra copy goes back to the first remote shell running as `normal_user@ad`, which will then send it to `/dev/null`.