# No such file or directory. But it exists

Tags: bash, ubuntu, virtual-machine, fstab

I'm trying to access the `etc/fstab` by the following command and getting the error.

Bash command:

```
sudo echo "swapfile none swap sw 0 0" >> etc/fstab
```

Error:

```
-bash: etc/fstab: No such file or directory
```

Then when I trying to check the existence of `etc/fstab` by `ls -l` and getting it there. But why I got an error in the first entry point?

Btw, I'm using Ubuntu server on my Virtual machine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirecting stdout to a file you don't have write permission on](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1416/redirecting-stdout-to-a-file-you-dont-have-write-permission-on)

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov doesn't quite answer all the question

Comment: Do you mean `/etc/fstab` or `etc/fstab`? Are you in the root directory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two issues here

1. The file path needs the leading `/` here, so it should be `/etc/fstab`
2. You'll then find that despite your `sudo` command you get a "permission denied" error. This is answered at [Redirecting stdout to a file you don't have write permission on](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1416/100397)

Comment: Thank you, but in the second point as you mentioned I get an error about permissions. I tried to add "tee" keyword but error caused again.

Comment: permission denied :)

Comment: @danilpopov You need to modify the `tee` command with `sudo`, not the `echo` command.

Comment: @Shadur Yes I did it, removed `echo`, and added a `sudo tee` . But it didn't helped.

Comment: Please show us! Edit your question to add  the new command and its result

Comment: @Danil  Point (2) above explains this. Your non-sudo shell does all redirections *first* (because the commands in the pipeline have to inherit the file description when they are started). The sudo comes too late. Read the reference, please.

Comment: ... At this point I *really* urge the OP not to monkey around with `/etc/fstab` using scripts they don't understand, because  odds of them breaking something critical approach 1.