# Why sudo -u not working for folder that is owned by the user

Tags: permissions

Considering there is hierarchy of directory in a mounted drive

```
|-ssd-drive
    |-main
        |-sub
```

Following are access of folder main, sub

```
 drwxrwxrwx. 12 poweruser devgroup 4096 Oct 26 18:45 main
 drwxrwxr-x. 8 poweruser poweruser 4096 Oct 26 19:01  sub
```

Now when I tried to run a shell script and on user `poweruser` behalf, and output the log under `sub` directory, it failed with permission issue

```
[myaccount@vm-002 log]$ sudo -u poweruser /script.sh  > /ssd-drive/main/sub/app.log 2>&1
-bash: /ssd-drive/main/sub/app.log: Permission denied
```

Why `sudo -u poweruser` doesn't work in this case? It's the owner of the owning directory

Comment: Redirection is handled by the interactive shell not sudo - see for example [Redirecting stdout to a file you don't have write permission on](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1416/redirecting-stdout-to-a-file-you-dont-have-write-permission-on)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by steeldriver - the redirect is not part of the sudo.

a work around would be to run via bash:

```
sudo -u poweruser bash -c "/script.sh  > /ssd-drive/main/sub/app.log 2>&1"
```

This way the redirect is handled by a new instance of bash that is run as `poweruser`